# Image reconstruction after applying dwt and reconstruction to save computational time

Tags: image, matlab

I have applied dwt2 on 2D image, applied source and channel coding on LL sub band and transmitted it.

Now I have a question on the receiver side. Do I have to apply source and channel coding on HL, LH, HH and transmit as well to reconstruct the image on the other end (using idwt)? Is it possible to reconstruct LL sub band without the rest? I am asking this so as to save the computational time. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: You need the other subbands if you want to do a source reconstruction.  The LL band is essentially a low-pass filtered version of your image and so all of the high-frequency information / edges are stored in the other subbands.

Answer (score 0):

The low passed part and high passed part of a wavelet decomposed signal are independent (actually orthogonal to each other), for a 2D image, you will have four sub-images after one level of decomposition and all of them are not related to each other.

So if the low frequency blurred image (LL part) is all you want to recover on the receiver side, you won't need the other parts.

Comment: Thank you so much Steven. But I am implementing the following code for image recovery which requires the rest of the sub bands too: sX=size(Im);
[LL,HL,LH,HH]=dwt2(Im,Wave_Name); 
H = idwt2(LL_block,LH,HL_block,HH,Wave_Name,sX); I beleive I need to look for another which recovers only the low passed part. Any suggestions or help are much welcome.

Comment: So it's a programming application question.
You can simply set the others HL, LH, HH to zeros. For example,
    HL = zeros(sX);
Thinking physically, they're not transmitted as it's lossy compression.